# How can I solve for the eigenvalues for this 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the eigenvalues are $0, 0, 6$ but I just don't understand how it was solved. To be more precise, please explain the last few steps.

The matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: have you tried solving the equation $| A - \lambda I | = 0$? if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: A eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a complex number such that $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ has non-trivial solutions. What values of $\lambda$ will make it happen?

Answer (score 3):

Every eigenvector for a nonzero eigenvalue will be in the column space, and since the column space here is one-dimensional, *every* nonzero vector in it is an eigenvector. So the first step here is to find out what is the eigenvalue corresponding to $[1\;1\;1]^T$. That is $6$.

Furthermore, since the matrix is not invertible, we know that $0$ is an eigenvalue, and the corresponding eigenspace is the null space. We can easily find a basis for that, such as $[2\;-1\;0]^T$ and $[3\;0\;-1]^T$.

This covers all the possibilities for both zero and nonzero eigenvalues (and besides, we have three linearly independent eigenvectors, so there isn't room for more of them).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If you want calculate the eigenvalues in the ''classical'' method note that:
$$\det
\begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2-\lambda & 3\\ 1 & 2 & 3-\lambda \end{bmatrix} =6\lambda^2-\lambda^3
$$

and find the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the system for an arbitrary $\lambda$
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1x&+&2y&+&3z&=&\lambda x\\
1x&+&2y&+&3z&=&\lambda y\\
1x&+&2y&+&3z&=&\lambda z
\end{array}\right.$$
The first remark you can make is that $\lambda x=\lambda y=\lambda z$. Therefore, if $\lambda\neq 0$ we have $x=y=z$. For eigenvectors, $x=y=z$ cannot be zero. The first line gives
$x+2x+3x=\lambda x$, from which you get $\lambda=6$. Now if $\lambda=0$ the system becomes a single equation $$x+2y+3z=0.$$
This is the equation of a plane, a vectorial space of dimension 2, therefore
the eigenvalue 0 is twice degenerated.